# JXR images larger than original - imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg

I am looking for the proper procedure to convert images to JXR format.

I am using an ubuntu system and the only method I can get to work is via a 2 step process:

```
convert 1.png 1.hdr && convert 1.hdr 1.jxr
```

The problem is that it takes my 11KB png file and spits out a 970KB jxr file.

I have tried using tif and bmp as the intermediate format, but it errors and gives the JxrEncApp man page.

- ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114
- Not sure what version of JxrEncApp (copyright M$ 2013)

Comment: Do you have  jxrlib as a delegate in your Imagemagick. Does it show in the list of delegates when you do convert -version? This page https://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php says it is read/write compatible. Perhaps your IM version is too old or your  jxrlib is too old. Check here https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=jxrlib for issues and versions and any options. Do you get any error messages when you do `convert image.png image.jxr`? Have you tried `convert image.png JXR:image.jxr`? See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707223(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is your PNG 8-bit color or 24-bit color?

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you for your input. When I try the command you suggested, it responds with the man page for JxeEncApp. You can check my png file from here https://nickschild.com/1.png

Comment: Your png is only 8-bit color with only 3 colors in it. So it will be very small.  I think JPX is a JPG extended format, which is likely to be 24-bit compressed. That means it goes from 8-bits with only 3 colors to millions of color and so will be larger. The compression may not be adequate to get a small file size. You should check to see if there are compression quality options with that format. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_XR. Sorry I have no experience with JPX format. Nevertheless, Imagemagick should be able to convert directly.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. What about this image: https://nickschild.com/2.jpg orig: 102KB, JXR: 879KB

Comment: Perhaps different compression levels. Did you check the JXR format for quality/compression settings? What does Imagemagick's identify -verbose tell you about the quality and compression?